# How Sorting Multi-Column Grouping in Stimulsoft Report

Tags: sorting, group-by, stimulsoft

I work on a report with Stimulsoft Report V2011.3

in my report I have a `GroupHeaderBand` that have 2 column for grouping data (like under)

```
{Tbl1.c1}{Tbl1.c2}
```

then i set `Sort Direction` equal to `Descending` (`Sort Direction` apply on whole of `GroupHeaderBand`, this means that the both of `Tbl1.c1` & `Tbl1.c2` are Descending)

but I want `Tbl1.c1` be `Desc` & `Tbl1.c2` be `Asc`.

how do that?

Answer (score 0):

It's better to add two Group Headers with one column for each.